# Strange "IOException was unhandled"

Tags: vb.net, exception

(VB.NET, .NET 3.5)

I wrote the following function to read some text from txt file. It was working fine but now it's not. It keeps giving me this error message

"IOException was unhandled" and

" The process cannot access the file 'F:\kh_matt\ch1.txt' because it is being used by another process."

The ch1.txt is not even opened or being used by any program at all. I tried to move ch1.txt to another location (Drive D) still I got the same message error but just different location it says The process cannot access the file 'D:\ch1.txt' because it is being used by another process."

Here's my code block :

Private Sub btnRead_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click

```
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim filelocation As String

    filelocation = "F:\kh_matt\ch1.txt"
    Dim chid As Integer

    chid = 1


    If System.IO.File.Exists(filelocation) = True Then
        reader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(filelocation, FileMode.Open))
    Else
        MsgBox(filelocation, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End If

    Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filelocation))
    Dim vArray() As String = MyStream.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar("$"))
    MyStream.Close()


    Dim count As Integer

    For d As Integer = 0 To vArray.Length - 1 Step 1

        If d = vArray.Length - 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        InsertKh(chid, d + 1, vArray(d))
        count = d + 1
    Next


    MsgBox("Done Inserting")
End Sub
```

It always points to this code :

**Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filelocation))**

Where I debug and press the respective button. Can anyone point out what the problem is ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you open the file twice, which is probably what's causing your error:

```
reader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(filelocation, FileMode.Open))
...
Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filelocation))
```

Are you sure that's what you intend to do? It looks like you can remove `MyStream` and use `reader` instead. Also, you don't have to use `Path.Combine`, since `filelocation` is not relative.

Comment: Yeah, you got that right. Now I commented out this code block :

        'If System.IO.File.Exists(filelocation) = True Then
        '    reader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(filelocation, FileMode.Open))
        'Else
        '    MsgBox(filelocation, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        'End If

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(filelocation) = True Then
    reader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(filelocation, FileMode.Open))
```

If the file exists it will open a StreamReader on it, then try and open another StreamReader on the same file, which will lock the file, causing this line:

```
Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filelocation))
```

to fail.

Also, some pointers:

- consider using the System.IO.File.ReadAllText() method instead, much easier
- if you **must** use streams, wrap them in a using block to ensure they're freed correctly, for example:

`

```
Dim vArray() As String

using (Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filelocation))
{
  vArray = MyStream.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar("$"))
}
```

(sorry if the above code isn't 100% correct, I don't write much VB.Net)

Comment: Good call with the `ReadAllText`. Didn't know that one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you close your stream & streamreader once you've finished reading the file, even when an exception is being thrown.

Use a try/finally block, and close the stream / streamreader in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the reply. It's my mistake. I forgot to comment out my code that I wrote for testing earlier. After commenting this code out it works like before.

```
    'If System.IO.File.Exists(filelocation) = True Then
    '    reader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(filelocation, FileMode.Open))
    'Else
    '    MsgBox(filelocation, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    'End If
```

Have a good day.